# Writing to a file in production with sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, production

I cannot write to a file for the life of me using Sinatra in production.

In my development environment, I can use `Logger` without a problem  and log STDOUT to a file.

It seems like in production, the `Logger` class is overwritten by the RACK middleware's `Logger` and it makes things more complicated.

I simply want to write to a file like this:

```
post '/' do
  begin
  $log_file = File.open("/home/ec2-user/www/logs/app.log", "w")
  ...do..stuff...
  $log_file.write "INFO -- #{Time.now} --\n #{notification['Message']}"
  ...do..stuff...
  rescue
  $log_file.write "ERROR -- #{Time.now} --" +  "\njob failed"
  ensure
  $log_file.close
  end
end
```

The file doesn't get created when I receive a POST request to '/'.

However the file DOES get created when I load the app running pry:

```
pry -r ./app.rb
```

I am certain the code inside the POST block is effectively running because new jobs are getting added to the database upon receiving requests..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note: It's almost always better to have a singleton class than a global variable like `$log_file`. Namespaces help keep code organized and avoid naming conflicts. Each module "owns" its local namespace, but the global variable space is shared, so there's usually a lot of problems there.

Comment: Does production Sinatra have file/directory permissions to create a file there? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Amadan it works fine from IRB though. I think I would be getting permission errors when I create the file from the REPL also but that is good point. I will see if it has anything to do with that.

Comment: If it was getting executed as, say, `www-data` user, then it would likely have different permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get to the bottom of this.

I changed the nginx user in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` from `nginx` to `ec2-user`. (Ideally I would just fix the write permissions for the `nginx` user but this solution suits me for now.)

Then I `ps aux | grep unicorn` and saw the timestamp next to the process name: `unicorn master -c unicorn.rb -D` was 3 days old!!

All this time I was pushing my code the the production server, restarting nginx and never killed and restart the unicorn process.

I removed all the code in my POST block and left only the file creation part

```
post '/' do
  $log_file = File.open("/home/ec2-user/www/logs/app.log", "a")
  $log_file.write("test log string")
  $log_file.close
end
```

And the the file was successfully written to upon receiving a POST request.

Comment: In Ruby, variables that start with a `$` are global variables. Do NOT use global vars :-) (simply do `log_file = File....`)